# Exclude 01-00-1900 result from TEXT formula in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I am using the TEXT function to convert field date_Field_ABC values like so: =TEXT([@[date_Field_ABC]], "mm-dd-yyyy") which works fine, but how do I extend the same TEXT formula so that the default values of 01-00-1900 do not show at all (from when date_Field_ABC is empty)?
Thank you

Comment: Something like: `=TEXT([@[date_Field_ABC]], "[>0]mm-dd-yyyy;;;")`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you @RonRosenfeld. I don't see an up arrow next to your response, how do I mark this as resolved?

Comment: Glad to help. I'll add it as an answer which you can mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
=TEXT([@[date_Field_ABC]], "mm-dd-yyyy;;;")
```

In my comment I included the conditional `[>0]` but it isn't necessary and should be omitted.

The format string is interpreted as:

- return a formatted date for a positive value
- return nothing for a negative value, zero value, or text value

Comment: I guess I'm too new here, when I try to upvote I get "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @endOfTunnel You did mark it as the answer, and that's good enough for now.  You'll earn that reputation in no time if you hang around.